# Trigonometry problem - prove that $\cos(\beta)=1-1/(8\cos^2(\alpha))$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

> $ABC$ is Isosceles triangle ($AB=AC$) and $\angle ABC= \angle ACB = \alpha$. A point $F$ is chosen on the opposite side of $AC$ from $B$ such that $AF=CF=BC$ and $\angle FAC = \angle FCA = \beta$. Show that $$\cos(\beta)=1-\frac{1}{8\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

I showed that if the question was true then $AB=AC=BC$ but I don't know how to prove the question..

[image: Diagram 3312658]

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/classic/nheszdr2

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I don't understand what you are trying to say..

Comment: I'ts a Geogebra construction I constructed to try to analyze the problem. Just sharing.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales oh, ok, anyway I am pretty sure the problem is simply incorrect. as I wrote to Michael Rozenberg, I'm pretty sure I found a counterexample (construct a triangle with base length 1 and base angles = 30 degrees, and take F such that BETA = arccos(1/(2*sqrt3)) which is about 73 degrees (the same BETA as in the diagram) and it's easy to show that the problem does not hold in this case (my motivation for the counter example is that I already showed that if the problem is true then ABC has all sides equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$BC=2AC\cos\alpha=2(2FC\cos\beta)=4BC\cos\alpha\cos\beta,$$ which gives
$$4\cos\alpha\cos\beta=1.$$

Comment: I know, and I got to this myself. I am not sure how does this help to finish the problem. I am actually starting to think the problem is false and I'm trying to build a counterexample.

Comment: @Omer Just we have no any relation between this equality and what we need to prove. I think, there is a mistake in the given.

Comment: Yes, the question is wrong, I just found a counterexample...